# Why I cannot set break points on certain kind of return statements?

Tags: java, android

Consider this simple program snippet written in Android studio:
[image]

[image]

When you put break pointers inside the functions, if the return type is boolean or integer android studio tell you there is no executable code on the first return statement. But it works if the return type is String. Actually for int and boolean return type if the first return statement is actually hit the debugger will highlight the second return statement. Which is obviously wrong. I tried on several projects, this behavior is consistent.

I wrote a plain java application in eclipse with same piece of code. I don't see this error occurs there. I am not sure if this is an Android studio IDE bug or there is really no executable code there. If there is really no executable code there, why?

Comment: Conjecture: is it some sort of optimization, that `return (time % 2 == 0);` and `return time % 2;` is actually what is executed? What if the int return values aren't 0 and 1?

Comment: @AndyTurner This makes sense. I will try changing the values.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right if I change the return value for debuggerTest3 the issue disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be as a result of intellij optimizing your code for you.

```
if (time % 2 == 0) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

can be written as

```
return time % 2 == 0;
```

Note that there is a "hint" on the `if` in the screenshot, which could well be a "Simplify", to make this transformation.